# How to write the following SQL command in the right way - SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TriggerName))
    DROP TRIGGER @TriggerName
```

I can't find the right syntax to use `@TriggerName` (I think I did it ok inside the `OBJECT_ID`, but I can't find the right way for the `DROP TRIGGER` name).

I need to drop the trigger if it already exists.

I get this error from my current SQL statement:

> Incorrect syntax near '@TriggerName'. Expecting '.', ID, or Quoted_ID.

Comment: `OBJECT_ID(@TriggerName)` doesn't work?

Comment: Yeah it works! will remove that, but i still got a problem with 
DROP TRIGGER @TrigerName.  
"Incorrect syntax near '@TrigerName'.Expecting '.', ID, or Quoted_ID."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use dynamic SQL for this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.triggers WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(@TriggerName))
BEGIN
    DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);

    SET @sql = 'DROP TRIGGER @TriggerName';
    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, '@TriggerName', @TriggerName);
    exec sp_executesql @sql;
END;
```

I don't think the `DROP` syntax allows a variable to be substituted for an identifier name.

Comment: Correct idea, but the string replacement of @TriggerName is unnecessary, and the trigger name in sys.triggers can be checked by the name column, instead of going via object_id (except the same trigger name might exist as DML and DDL trigger, then check also parent_class)

Comment: @ErikHart . . . `OBJECT_ID` is convenient if the name might be qualified or partially qualified.  But that was the OP's original code that seemed to work for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

You can't specify the trigger name in DROP TRIGGER by a variable. You either need a specific, hardcoded name, or dynamic SQL (here actually DDL).

```
declare @ddl nvarchar(2000)
if exists(...)
begin
    set @ddl=N'drop trigger ' + @triggerName
    exec sp_executesql @ddl
end
```

Be careful anyway, to not get user input as trigger name, which would be a serious security risk.

BTW: is there a reason why you don't query the 'name' column in sys.triggers directly?